# TortoiseSVN 1.8 merge problems

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Im using Tortoise 1.8 with windows 7. I do the followings

1. Create a branch in REpo browser
2. check out the branch
3. Make changes in the branch
4. commit.pressed F5 in repository browser. all thing is on the server.
5. check out the trunk
6. I would merge the changed branch to the trunk with "Merge two different trees" but the tortoise merged the branch without conflicts.

What cause the errors?

Unfortunately I must not upgrade the clients till not solve that issue.

Comment: What errors are you talking about?

Comment: I mean, I would see the difference between the two files.
I want to merge it manually in Tortoise.

Comment: Did you consider to use "merge a range of revisions"?

Comment: why would you use "merge 2 different trees", that's for merging scenarios such as between 2 unrelated repositories. For this scenario, use the 'merge range of revisions' option.

Comment: Merge range of revisions worked similar. Get the same problem

Comment: If I use "Merge range of revisions" the trunk was changed but not send a conflict. I am still can not select what changes I want to merge into the trunk what not.E.g in the changed file I want to merge the row 50 but I don't want to merge the row 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect conflicts? Could you show "From", "To", "Working Copy" paths from merge dialog?

Probably, you specified wrong working copy path.

Could you try `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\component1\trunk` instead of `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\component1`

From tortoisesvn help:

Merge two different trees

This is a more general case of the reintegrate method. What you are asking Subversion to do is: “Calculate the changes necessary to get [FROM] the head revision of the trunk [TO] the head revision of the branch, and apply those changes to my working copy (of the trunk).” The net result is that trunk now looks exactly like the branch.

So if you want to see changes in your trunk dir you should specify your working copy path the same as your trunk dir.

Comment: From : http://svn_server/svn/Training/component01/branches/changed_branch

To : http://svn_server/svn/Training/component01/trunk

working copy:C:\Users\myname\Desktop\component1

Comment: on my workspace C:\Users\myname\Desktop\component1\ not contains trunk folder

Comment: On my workspace the component1 directory not contains trunk subfolder and when I choose "merge two different trees" I can not change the workspace because I choose the "merge two..." option on the folder.
I checked out the trunk directly into this folder. This component1 folder is equal my component1's trunk.

Comment: yep, that is my mistake, sorry. So, what is 'Test merge' result?

Comment: Merging differences between repository URLs - C:\users...
    Merged - C:\users...
    Completed! - C:\users...

Comment: I do anything, simple merge the files.
When I made now a new branch with changes, it is merged without any questions.

Comment: If your working copy is clean and you just have changed existed files in branch there shouldn't be any merge conflic. There will be tree conflicts if you add files in branch. Which one do you expect?

Comment: @johny there won't be tree conflicts just by adding a new file in the branch, I would expect the merge to happen without any issue.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I tried it in local repo and I had an tree conflict.

Comment: I reinstalled the tortoiseSVN.
Still not get a conflict when I would merge the changed branch in to the Trunk-s working copy.
Deleted the old config files, installed the Tortoise with the own cli tool.
I have no idea what caused this

Comment: I do it again with the following steps.
1. I made the branch from my trunk.
2. I made changes on this branch.
3. I would merge back my branch into the trunk.

For this operation I would use "Merge two different trees"

I choosed on the merged different trees option on check outed trunk workspace with the following settings.

From : My_Branch
To: My trunk
Working copy: My checkouted trunk

whan I click Merge. the SVN merged the branch into the trunk without conflicts. But I commit changes to the branch before.

Comment: Was the trunk changed after that?

Comment: The trunk were not changed.

Comment: If I use "Merge range of revisions" the trunk was changed but not send a conflict. I am still can not select what changes I want to merge into the trunk what not.E.g in the changed file I want to merge the row 50 but I don't want to merge the row 75

Comment: I found the problem. It was in my main concept.
If I would merge a branch into the trunk, the best way to use "Merge range of revisions". After the merge is success ,I can accept or change the merge details with  "Check modifications" option. Thank you all for the help.